# Load and submit user profile form

Tags: forms

I want to programmatically load the user profile form for a specific user and submit it ( in order to trigger hook_form_submit() in another module ).  So far I have :

```
module_load_include('inc', 'user', 'user.pages');   
$account = user_load($uid);
$form = drupal_get_form('user_profile_form', $account);
```

but how do I submit the form ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more on the use case because I think you can just call a function that doesn't need to be triggered by a form's submit function.

Answer (score 0):

If oyu want to get and submit a form programatically you must use the function [drupal_form_submit](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_form_submit/7)

> Retrieves, populates, and processes a form.
>
> This function allows you to supply values for form elements and submit
>   a form for processing. Compare to drupal_get_form(), which also builds
>   and processes a form, but does not allow you to supply values.

Check this function's documentation page and its comments for some examples.